# Web application is not loading after redeployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx

I have the following situation:

I have a react web application that is deployed on an NGINX web server via Jenkins. In some cases, my web application does not show up in the browser after I deployed a new version of the application. When you open the web application, it only shows a text: "Loading...".

A quick solution to this problem is to delete your browser data and refresh the web application.

**My question:** What is the possible cause for this problem or how can I find out what the cause is? I don't want that the users of this application have to delete their browser data when I deploy a new version.

Comment: what does Jenkins build log says? is the build was successful?

Comment: @Roy.B Yes, the build was successful and everything works well after I deleted my browser data.

Comment: sounds like you need some purge logic

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, It could be because of several reasons:

1) The javascript could be breaking.

2) You might be using some caching strategy that causes the javascript to be cached. Service worker for example.

3) Problem with your react router configuration.

4) A network call might be taking too long to respond.

Need a minimum reproducible example to debug further.

Comment: Point 2 sounds promising. I have a service worker. I will research this a bit.